# Tools for xlf/xmb files

Tags: internationalization, angular5, xlform

I am using JIT translation for my project and my translation files are in .xlf format.

But clients/partners who will do the translation dont have much of technical knowledge so they might find it difficult to read xlf file and provide translations.

So can somebody tell me what are the tools that help to open/deal with xlf(translation) files of angular-i18n?

Answer (score 2):

[@ngx-i18nsupport](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport) is the best tool that I found. As you can see in its README it includes 4 subsets:

- [tooling](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/blob/master/projects/tooling): Schematics for adding @ngx-i18nsupport to your projects, for updating to current version, and builder support.
- [xliffmerge](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/blob/master/projects/xliffmerge): The command line tool that does all the magic
- [ngx-i18nsupport-lib](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/blob/master/projects/ngx-i18nsupport-lib): A library to support working with xliff 1.2, xliff 2.0 and xmb/xtb file
- [tiny-translator](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/blob/master/projects/tiny-translator): A web application to translate xliff 1.2, xliff 2.0 and xmb/xtb files to other languages

The first is probably the thing that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Those are standard XLIFF files - any of the editors listed on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF) will do, and if you are using professional translators (LSP) then they should already be familiar with those.

Note that the [xliffmerge](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/tree/master/projects/xliffmerge) indicated in the answer above is very useful in pre-processing, because by default Angular won't add the  elements (the ones that will hold the translations) to the .xlf file.